# Can't install BeautifulSoup in Eclipse on Mac

Tags: python, eclipse, macos, beautifulsoup, pydev

```
ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup
```

I already tried `easy_intall` and `python setup.py install`, neither works. Even after I installed the BeautifulSoup, I still got the same error.

I have pre-installed python 2.7.2 and python 2.7 and 3.2 from python.org.

I installed the soup in the directory of python 2.7 according to terminal, as following.

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.0.3-py2.7.egg-info
Writing /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.0.3-py2.7.egg-info
```

Comment: You need to check which python interpreter Eclipse is using. Did you install BS to the builtin Mac python version, or to one that you installed later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've installed Beautiful Soup 4 ("beautifulsoup4-4.0.3-py2.7.egg-info"), but you're using the import statement for Beautiful Soup 3.

The package name was changed from "BeautifulSoup" to "bs4" so that both versions could coexist on the same installation.

Change your import statement to something like this and it should work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

For more information, see the documentation section ["Porting code to BS4"](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#porting-code-to-bs4). BS4 is not completely backwards compatible with BS3, but most BS3 code should work once you change the import statement.

Comment: i changed to "from bs4". it is fixed. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

If all else fails, just put the BeautifulSoup source in your python directory. Like in ~/Python_install_dir/Lib/

Comment: +1: Really, using BeautifulSoup is just a matter of putting a text file in your source directory. Using package managers or installers for such a simple and beautiful library as BeautifulSoup is overcomplicating the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you use the same interpreter as for installation?
If you have 2 python interpreters (for example 2.6 and 2.7) and installed BeautifulSoup with 2.6 easy_install, it won't be available in your 2.7.